# Refresh webview if external page closed

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to make the web-view refresh if the external page is closed 
Here is the code of the fragment where the webview is :

```html
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {   
          
          if(url.contains("ex03"))
          { 

           view.getContext().startActivity(
                         new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                 
           return true;
           
          } else {
           
                 view.loadUrl(url); 
                 return true;
             }
            
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple answer will be `webView.reload();` after external page is closed

and have a look --> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563482/5188159)